# Python - Thread calling scripts with arguments

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a python script script01.py which takes 4 arguments

I launch script01.py in batch command like this : python script01.py arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4

Now I would like to launch script01.py in parallel using Thread (or any suitable method) and passing the arguments :

```
Thread 1 launchs : script01.py A B C D
Thread 2 launchs : script01.py E F G H
Thread 3 launchs : script01.py I J K L
...
```

How could I manage this ?

Thanks

Comment: https://medium.com/codex/reading-files-fast-with-multi-threading-in-python-ff079f40fe56

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you would need a control function that then threads and launches script01.py

for the sake of an example script01 is just a function.

```
import threading
import time


def script01(thread_name, numbers): # Square of numbers
    for number in numbers:
        print(thread_name, number**2)
        time.sleep(1)

def launcher(*args):
    size = len(args)
    group = size // 4
    threads = {}
    for i in range(group):
        threads[i] = threading.Thread(target=script01, args=("thread" + str(i), args[i*4:(i+1)*4]))
    for i in range(group):
        threads[i].start()
    for i in range(group): # Joins the threads to wait for all to be complete before moving on. 
        threads[i].join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    launcher(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16)
```

output looks like this:

```
thread0 1
thread1 25
thread2 81
thread3 169
thread0 4
thread2 100
thread3 196
thread1 36
thread0 9
thread3 225
thread2 121
thread1 49
thread0 16
thread1 64
thread2 144
thread3 256
```